# Why won't array take random, shuffle, limit, etc.?

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, random, limit

In my Rails controller code I would like to randomly retrieve three of each content:

```
@content = Content.includes(:author).find(params[:id])    
content_sub_categories = @content.subcategories

related_content = []
content_sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
  related_content << sub_cat.contents
end

@related_content = related_content.rand.limit(3)
```

`rand.limit(3)` isn't working, and the errors include:

```
undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0x007f9e19806bf0>
```

I'm familiar with Rails but still in the process of learning Ruby. Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Perhaps it could be I am also rendering out the content in this way `<%= @related_content %>`?

I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.14
- Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Please paste full error trace.

Answer (score 7):

`limit` is a a method on ActiveRecord relations (that adds `LIMIT X`) to the SQL generated. However you have an array not a relation, hence the error.

The equivalent array method is `take`. You can of course combine both the shuffling and the limit into one step by using the `sample` method

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pick 3 random elements, use [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
related_content.sample(3)
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you for the response. Weirdly, for whatever reason I can't find, sample(3) isn't working either. It doesn't throw an error, but still displays all of the content.

Comment: Problem is somewhere else then. I'm sure `#sample` works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Do you think it could be in regards to that I'm printing the content like so <%= @related_content %>

Comment: Not likely. If you print value of `@related_content` to the console, what do you see? Also show your current version of code

Comment: I'm looking at it more and it's giving a sample of the 3 subcategories - but I'm looking for a sample of the 3 contents... do you have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
related_content = []
content_sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
  related_content << sub_cat.contents.sample(3) # add 3 random elements
end
@related_content = related_content
```

Or without temporary variables using `map`:

```
@related_content = @content.subcategories.map { |cat| cat.contents.sample(3) }
```

Note that `@related_content` is an array of (3-element) arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have it much closer now... see below. One problem is that it's repeating content - even the content that I am currently in ( so if I in the show of content 6 and trying to show related articles... it's still showing content 6 below) Is there a way to validate the uniqueness of?

Answer (score 0):

How is this ?

```
a = (1..10).to_a
p a.sample(3)
# >> [4, 10, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final answer for finding the content id's subcategories, all of these subcategory's contents and displaying the content without repeats:

```
def show
  @content = Content.includes(:author).find(params[:id])
  related_content = @content.subcategories.pluck(:id)
  @related_content = Content.joins(:subcategories).published.order('random()').limit(3).where(subcategories: { id: related_content}).where('"contents"."id" <> ?', @content.id)
end
```